# disable button untill form filled with specific length

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to create a form which needs to be filled with 9 numeric digits. I would like the submit button to be disabled untill the form is filled exactly with 9 digits. I have found many scripts with button disabled untill form is filled but not with specific length. Could you please help me?

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" name='text1' maxlength="9" class="phone-input">
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="phonenumber(document.form1.text1); changeDiv();"/>                     
    </form>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Markus, you can use the `pattern` attribute to validate the input (specify `\d` to allow only digits), in addition to `required`. The `validity.valid` property of the text field can then be used to enable/disable the button in the `input` event handler:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input id="txtPhone" type="text" name='text1' pattern="\d{9}" required maxlength="9" class="phone-input" >
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form> 
<script>
    document.getElementById("txtPhone").addEventListener("input", function () {
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = !this.validity.valid;
    });
</script>
```

```js
document.getElementById("txtPhone").addEventListener("input", function () {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = !this.validity.valid;
});
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <input id="txtPhone" type="text" name='text1' pattern="\d{9}" required maxlength="9" class="phone-input" >
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="alert('Submit!');" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a pattern. Didn't try it, but it must be something like this:

```
<input pattern=".{9}">
```

Comment: I didn't know about the pattern, thank you but it's not solution in this case, i need to have a button disabled, not just a field with specific length